# Ajax refresh .erb code after successful creating object.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

How to tell Ajax to refresh `.erb` code after I have successfully made new `Box`? I'm using rails 4.

`views/modifications/show.html.erb`

```
<tbody id="boxes_count"> 
    <% @modification.box.each do |b| %> 
      <tr><%= b.name %></tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

`views/boxes/create.js.erb`

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @modification.boxes.last) %>").appendTo("#boxes_count");
```

Answer (score 0):

`views/modifications/show.html.erb`

```
<tbody id="boxes_count"> 
    <%= render :boxes_content, boxes: @modification.boxes %>
</tbody>
```

`views/modifications/_boxes_content.html.erb`

```
<% boxes.each do |b| %> 
  <tr><%= b.name %></tr>
<% end %>
```

`views/boxes/create.js.erb`

```
$("#boxes_count").html('<%=j render(:boxes_content ,boxes: @modification.boxes) %>');
```

Comment: it doesn't work! And why you named new file _table_body, if you don't rencer it that name?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems good, perhaps lacking some context in the question.

If you're trying to call this code *concurrently*, it won't work (IE if you're trying to show the updated `show.html.erb` whilst you update the `boxes` from another page)...

---

If you're trying to create a box through ajax, and append the new element to your current page, I don't see why your current code doesn't work.

We've done something similar (http://firststopcosmeticshop.herokuapp.com -- try adding an item to the cart & then removing):

[image]

The trick with Ajax is to make your code as modular as possible. This was suggested by `Wayne Chu` -- here's what I'd do:

```
#app/views/modifications/show.html.erb
<%= link_to "New", modification_boxes_path, method: :post, remote: true %>
<tbody id="boxes_count"> 
   <%= render @modification.boxes %>
</tbody>

#app/views/modifications/_box.html.erb
<tr>
   <td><%= box.name %></td>
</tr>

#app/controllers/boxes_controller.rb
class BoxesController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :html, only: :create
   def create
      @modification = Modification.find params[:modification_id]
      @box = @modification.boxes.new box_params
      @box.save
   end

   private

   def box_params
      params.require(:box).permit(:name)
   end 
end

#app/views/boxes/create.js.erb
$("<%=j render @box").appendTo("#boxes_count");
```